# Как получить frame footer в UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Имеется `UITableView`, с кастомным футером

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно-ли как нибудь получить `UIView` футера.
Если я задаю

```
print(tableView.headerView(forSection: 0) ?? "nil")
print(tableView.footerView(forSection: 0) ?? "nil")
```

мне оба объекта приходят `nil`

если я использую только метод:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

без методов:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

то `UIView` создается, но когда я начинаю использовать эти 2 метода, мне приходит `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что метод

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

Может принимать любой `UIView`
А метод `tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)` возвращает только `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Поэтому в методе `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

необходимо возвращать `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Тогда объект можно будет достать.